# Recyclerview adapter is loaded with square the amount of object in the database(e.g. 25 for 5, 16 for 4 etc)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView the holds the user's notifications. A new notification has a colored background where an old one has a white background. My data base holds the information about every notification saying whether it is new (simply sing 0 for new and 1 for seen).

I have on top a button for "Mark all as read". WHen clicked, I have a listener for the user's notifications and on every child added, it changes the value of that child from 0 to 1.
When that is done I would like to repopulate the recyclerView so all the notifications would have the proper background (white - for old notification).

I have a separate function that listens to notifications also with a child event listener, and that I am calling that function on every child added of the previous function.

Now the result of this SHOULD BE what I've described - for each child added, the notifications listener is called and then it loads all the notifications,so granted I should end up with square the amount of actual notifications. The reason I a confused is because I clear the adapter every time the listen to notifications function is called, so as far as I can understand, only the last time the function is called should stick, because all the previous calls have been cleared, but that is not the case.

Would appreciate help understanding why that happens. Thanks!

```
        notifications_mark_all_as_read.setOnClickListener {
            refFeedNotifications.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                    for (i in p0.children) {
                        val notificationsRef =
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                .getReference("/users/$uid/notifications/gallery/${i.key}/seen")
                        notificationsRef.setValue(1)

                        notificationsRecyclerAdapter.clear()
                        listenToNotifications()
                    }

                }

                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}

            })


        }


 private fun listenToNotifications() {

        notificationsRecyclerAdapter.clear()

        refFeedNotifications.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {

            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

                val notification = p0.getValue(Notification::class.java)

                if (notification != null) {
                    notificationsRecyclerAdapter.add(SingleFeedNotification(notification, activity as MainActivity))
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

function `onChildAdded` on firebase `ChildEventListener` will always be called at least once for every children after you assign your listener to database reference.

So in your case, after you clear your list, `onChildAdded` will add every notification data at your list, because you assign a new listener to database reference